# How can I select only the cases where there is a background color in Excel?

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to know how can I select a case by his **background color** ? My idea is to put all this selected cases in uppercase, I got already my macro for uppercase a specific column but I'm lost in the selection part.

My macro will uppercase all the cases in the column A:

```
Public Mmi As Boolean
Sub test()
Dim Lg%, i%
Lg = Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row
If Mmi = False Then
    For i = 2 To Lg
        Cells(i, 1) = UCase(Cells(i, 1)) 'maj
    Next i
    Mmi = True
Else
    Next i
End If
End Sub
```

I would like to just uppercase my selection (in this case my selection would be all the cases with a background color), how can I do this ?

I got the RGB code -> `RGB(0,176,240)`

Thank you very much for your help !

**EDIT**

This is the complete code to uppercase or lowercase. This might be helpful for other people. FYI, this macro was given by another SO member so I don't own the credit for making this one, I've just add/delete some things to adapt it to my personal use :)

```
Public Mmi As Boolean
Sub test()
Dim Lg%, i%
Lg = Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row
If Mmi = False Then
    For i = 2 To Lg
        Cells(i, 1) = UCase(Cells(i, 1)) 'majuscule
    Next i
    Mmi = True
 Else
    For i = 2 To Lg
        'Cells(i, 1) = LCase(Cells(i, 1)) 'minuscule
        Cells(i, 1) = Application.Proper(Cells(i, 1)) 'Nom propre
    Next i
    Mmi = False
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: so you're asking `if .colorindex <> 0 then`?

Comment: @Satanas  use backticks \` to surround your code. 
Also, I'm not sure why you are using `rgb()`, just use `0` as the color index for white.

Comment: @jclasley that's the first i've seen the term "backtick" that didn't involve hunting.  Will try to remember that as contextual for this site... typically just call it a grave (*gr-ahv*).

Comment: @Cyril, ha! I wouldn't have had any clue what you meant if you said grave. We both learned something today, eh?

Comment: i jus got learnt

Comment: Satanas, is this subroutine called within the loop of another subroutine?  Kind of curious the context of `Mmi` and how the boolean aspect is being utilized.

Comment: @Cyril I use this macro to lower case too :) I will post the complete macro on edit

Comment: @Satanas In the "Complete" macro you listed, `Mmi` has use, beyond the first occurrence.  In the "Else" scenario, it is set to `False`, rather than always being `True` once one match is made (first cell), as in your truncated code.

Comment: Additional point, `Mmi` is declated and is set to `False` until your truncated macro is run, where it is set to `True`.  As it's allocated in memory, if you run this macro again and again, it should be `True` until you close Excel.  Care needs to be taken with Public variables to ensure that you control their initial case and final case, rather than relying on implicit declarations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In trying to decipher more of what is happening with your code, and building off of the comment to determine if there is a background color or not, I would revise your code similar to:

```
Sub test()
    Dim Lg As Long, i As Long
    Lg = Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 2 to Lg Step 1
        If Cells(i, 1).Interior.ColorIndex <> 0 Then
            Cells(i, 1).Value = UCase(Cells(i, 1).Value) 'maj
        End if
    Next i
End Sub
```

This removes the public boolean check, which doesn't seem to be helping the loop you have generated, since the If-statement would be your boolean output.  I have no other indication the `Mmi` was needed elsewhere.

I also added in `.Value` to your cell-value references and specified `As Long` in the dimensioning (added `i`).

---

**Edit:**

Made one edit... dropping `.colorindex` for `.color`, adding in the `lcase()` for no background:

```
Sub test()
    Dim Lg As Long, i As Long
    Lg = Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 2 To Lg Step 1
        If Cells(i, 1).Interior.ColorIndex <> xlNone Then
            Cells(i, 1).Value = UCase(Cells(i, 1).Value) 'maj
        Else
            Cells(i, 1).Value = LCase(Cells(i, 1).Value) 'maj
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Example with mock-data showing the code execution:

[image]

Comment: Post script... the type declaration `%`, equivalent to "As Integer" is silently converted to "As Long" in newer versions of Excel.  If you want to define using the type declaration, use `&` (ampersand).  [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/data-types/type-characters).

Comment: First of all, thank you for all your help. I've tried your code and I'm still putting all the cases in uppercase. for example I got 30 cells on lowercase, 6 of them got a bg color and I'm still getting 30 cells in uppercase instead of 6.

Comment: @Satanas you would need to put an edit to yoru question to show what you've tried from this answer (can't reliably read code from a comment due to formatting).  From there we can see if something didn't come over completely or is inappropriate.

Answer (score -1):

Could always use the [Interior.Color](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.interior.color) property to verify the current color of the cell

> Cells(i, 1).Interior.Color = RGB(0,176,240)

Comment: Albeit you are making a point about identifying a cell, I don't believe that would help the simplicity of a boolean check for an interior color.  If that could be tied back to use in the OP's inquiry, then you would have a more helpful answer.